# Why do I get "Error in as.character.default(<S4 object of class "glmerMod">)" when using tryCatch?

Tags: r, try-catch, lme4

I am applying a linear model over a dataset, and using tryCatch to detect possible warnings, here's the script:

```
glm.m <- tryCatch(
    glmer(y ~ gene + (1|x) + (1|z), data =a, family="binomial"),
    warning= function(w){paste("warning",glmer(y ~ gene + (1|x) + (1|z), data =a, family="binomial"))})
```

I keep on getting this error message:

> Error in as.character.default() :    no
>   method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

which does disappear if I remove tryCatch and simply run the model. Unfortunately I need to use tryCatch to detect the rows which will give me warnings. 
Did anyone already encounter the same error in similar conditions? I did see other threads with similar errors, but nothing was helpful for my case.

Comment: `paste` is trying to convert the output of `glmer(y ~ gene + (1|x) + (1|z), data =a, family="binomial")` to a text string, but it doesn't know how. What are you actually trying to do in your `paste` expression?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to paste a "warning" to the rows which will give  me warnings just to find them, otherwise at the end I will only have a number of warning and I won't know which rows gave them, as I am applying the function to a dataframe